# Calculate the following integral involving $\cosh^2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have a problem with calculating the following integral

Given is a function $T(E)$ with constants $E$, $a$ and $U_0$, defined as

$$\sqrt {2m} \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\left(E+\frac{U_0}{\cosh^2(ax)}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2} }dx$$

I know that $\cosh^2 x=1-\sinh^2 x$ and how to rewrite them as exponential functions, but the negative square root really gives me some trouble. 
Maybe anyone got some tips on how to start as even *wolframalpha* could not give me a solution to this.
Kind Regards

Comment: You do not really need all the constants. Try a simplified version$$\int\frac{\cosh x\; dx}{\sqrt{1+\lambda\cosh^2 x}}.$$

Comment: Observe that $\cosh^2 x=1\color{red}{+}\sinh^2 x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
\sqrt {2m} \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\left(E+\frac{U_0}{\cosh^2(ax)}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2} }dx=\sqrt {2m} \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{\cosh(a x)}{\left(E(1+\sinh^2(ax))+U_0\right)^{1/2}}dx
$$ then one may notice that
$$
\left(\sinh (ax)\right)'=a\cosh (ax)
$$ obtaining a standard integral of the form
$$
\int_{\alpha_0}^{\alpha_1}\frac{du}{\sqrt{\alpha+u^2}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. One question left: how do i get rid of $U_0$ under the squareroot?

Comment: @MichaelMaier You are welcome! You may write $$\left(E(1+\sinh^2(ax))+U_0\right)^{1/2}=\left(E\sinh^2(ax)+(E+U_0)\right)^{1/2} $$ then factor out $E$ and set $\alpha:=(E+U_0)/E$.

Comment: Sorry....sat there for another hour but still could not figure out the exact solution, I am stuck after factoring out E and bringing the integral to the form which you denoted as standard integral

Comment: One gets $$\sqrt {2m} \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\left(E+\frac{U_0}{\cosh^2(ax)}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2} }dx=\frac{\sqrt {2m}}{a\cdot \sqrt{E}}\int_{\beta_1}^{\beta_2}\frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2+\alpha}}$$ with $\beta_1=\sinh (ax_1),\,\beta_2=\sinh (ax_2)$, $\alpha=\frac{E+U_0}{E}$. Conclude with $$\int_{\beta_1}^{\beta_2}\frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2+\alpha}}=\ln\left(\frac{\beta_2+\sqrt{\beta_2^2+\alpha}}{\beta_1+\sqrt{\beta_1^2+\alpha}} \right),\quad (\beta_1<\beta_2).$$ Hope now it's OK for you.